# Escape single backslash \ with two

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string and I want to escape backslash between the double quotes only. I tried doing this,

```
String s = "Hello\na = a.split(\"\n\")";
String tem = s.replaceAll("(?<=\")[^\\\\](?=\")", "\\\\");
```

But I get the following output,

```
# output
Hello
a = a.split("\")
```

I want it to be,

```
Hello
a = a.split("\n")
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: Not saying it's impossible, but as a general rule, regex is not the right tool for parsing code.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple:

Assuming the backslash and double quotes, always preceding \n character

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Hello\na = a.split(\"\n\")";
    String tem = s.replaceAll("\\\"\\n\\\"", "\\\"\\\\n\\\"");
    System.out.println(tem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something simpler ?

```
String s = "Hello\na = a.split(\"\n\")";
String tem = s.replaceAll("(\\)(?=\")", "\\\\");
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/oItJK7/2)
or [here](https://regex101.com/r/oItJK7/1)